# Is the rrdtool RRA XFF value useless if RRA step is 1?

Tags: rrdtool

According to [rrdcreate](https://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/rrdcreate.en.html) manual, the RRA definition has the following syntax:

```
RRA:{AVERAGE | MIN | MAX | LAST}:xff:steps:rows
```

**XFF**(`xfiles factor`) defines what part of a consolidation interval may be made up from *UNKNOWN* data while the consolidated value is still regarded as known. Am I correct, that if the **step** is 1, then XFF value doesn't matter because single PDP is used to build the RRA entry, i.e this single PDP is either present or not? For example, both `RRA:AVERAGE:0:1:12` and `RRA:AVERAGE:0.9999:1:12` are equal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is, yes, sort of.  When you have 1cdp=1pdp then the amount of data present in a CDP can logically only be 100% or 0%, and so all xff values in the range 100>xff>=0 are identical.  Note that we exclude 100 from this range!  An xff of 100 would not make sense unless your computer has a usb-attached crystal ball...

However this parameter becomes much more important once lower-resolution RRAs start to consolidate data over large windows, which is the primary function of the RRA.